# Finding the group of 3 minutes for each ID in Hive SQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, hadoop, hive

I am having data such as ,

```
ID  time
1   9/6/2016 00:01:00
1   9/6/2016 00:01:30
1   9/6/2016 00:02:00
1   9/6/2016 00:04:30
1   9/6/2016 00:05:30
1   9/6/2016 01:05:30
1   9/6/2016 05:05:30
1   9/6/2016 05:06:30
2   9/6/2016 01:55:00
2   9/6/2016 01:56:29
2   9/6/2016 01:57:31
2   9/6/2016 03:55:00
2   9/6/2016 04:13:00
2   9/6/2016 04:15:21
```

For each ID, I want to set a new variable called flag to 1 and check for the first value of time. From the first value of time, I want to check for entries which are within 3 minutes from the first entry and set every thing to 1. Once the time entries are above 3 minutes, I want to set the flag variable to 2 and then again check for entries within 3 minutes from that time and this needs to go on for each ID. I want to find 3 minutes groups for each ID, so that I can form sets for each ID.

The output which I want is,

```
ID  time              flag
1   9/6/2016 00:01:00   1
1   9/6/2016 00:01:30   1
1   9/6/2016 00:02:00   1
1   9/6/2016 00:04:30   2
1   9/6/2016 00:05:30   2
1   9/6/2016 01:05:30   2
1   9/6/2016 05:05:30   2
1   9/6/2016 05:06:30   2
2   9/6/2016 01:55:00   1
2   9/6/2016 01:56:29   1
2   9/6/2016 01:57:31   1
2   9/6/2016 03:55:00   2
2   9/6/2016 04:13:00   3
2   9/6/2016 04:15:21   3
```

Here for ID 1, the flag sets to 1 and keeps checking for 3 minute entries until 3rd row and once it is above 3 minutes, it sets to 2 and again starts checking for 3 minute entries. Similarly for ID 2 as well.

The following is what I tried,

```
select ID, time, rank() over (order by time) as rank from table_name;
```

This one is ranking for the entire table. I am thinking, we can rank it for each ID and then call the first value and subtract it with remaining values and write a sub query here.

Is there a better efficient way to do this? I am using Hive queries here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, your sample output is incorrect; for ID = 1, time = 01:05:30 is a full hour after 00:05:30, yet you have the same flag for both.

Here is a solution using exclusively Oracle SQL. Check the "flag changeover" condition; the way I wrote it, the new flag starts only when strictly greater than 3 minutes have passed. If you want to start the new count when exactly 3 minutes have passed, change the first inequality to non-strict and the second to strict.

The solution* uses a recursive factored subquery, so it requires Oracle 11.2 or above.

* Note: Logically I shouldn't have to subtract 3/(24*60) where I do; instead, the inequalities should compare against 3/(24*60). This works in Oracle 12, but it crashes the database on Oracle 11.2 with ORA-00600, which I was told is a marker for a known bug in the Oracle implementation of recursive queries in 11.2 (which was fixed in 12.1). I am a non-paying customer, so I don't have access to the bug info myself. I tested the query I posted below on Oracle 11.2 and it works, while the simplified version crashes. Both versions worked fine on 12.1.

```
with
     inputs ( id, time ) as (
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 00:01:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 00:01:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 00:02:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 00:04:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 00:05:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 01:05:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 05:05:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 1, to_date('9/6/2016 05:06:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 01:55:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 01:56:29', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 01:57:31', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 03:55:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 04:13:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('9/6/2016 04:15:21', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
     ),
     rec ( id, time, flag, time_diff ) as (
       select  id, time, 1, 
               time - min(time) over (partition by id order by time) - 3/(24*60)
         from  inputs
       union all
       select  id, time, flag + 1, 
               time - min(time) over (partition by id order by time) - 3/(24*60)
         from  rec
         where time_diff > 0
     )
select   id, time, flag
from     rec
where    time_diff <= 0
order by id, time
;
```

**Output**:

```
  ID TIME                      FLAG
---- ------------------- ----------
   1 06/09/2016 00:01:00          1
   1 06/09/2016 00:01:30          1
   1 06/09/2016 00:02:00          1
   1 06/09/2016 00:04:30          2
   1 06/09/2016 00:05:30          2
   1 06/09/2016 01:05:30          3
   1 06/09/2016 05:05:30          4
   1 06/09/2016 05:06:30          4
   2 06/09/2016 01:55:00          1
   2 06/09/2016 01:56:29          1
   2 06/09/2016 01:57:31          1
   2 06/09/2016 03:55:00          2
   2 06/09/2016 04:13:00          3
   2 06/09/2016 04:15:21          3

 14 rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [sessonize UDF](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/sessions.html) in DataFu.

Also, there is a nice post about the different options (hive, pig, python) available [here](https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/code/reshaping_data/sessionization.html).